# scjp question on enum

Tags: java, scjp

```
public enum Scale2 {

    GOOD('C') { 
        public char getGrade() { 
            return grade; 
        } 
    },
    BETTER('B') { 
        public char getGrade() { 
            return grade; 
        } 
    },
    BEST('A') { 
        public char getGrade() { 
            return grade; 
        } 
    };

    private char grade;

    Scale2(char grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    // (1) INSERT CODE HERE
    public char getGrade() { 
        return grade; 
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        System.out.println(GOOD.getGrade());
    }
}
```

This is a program from khalid mughal scjp guid and following are the options and questions. When I tried to run this in eclipse, Its saying the non static grade cannot access from static context,I think according to concept its right,but I am confused wheather book is write or I am...please replay.

Which code, when inserted at (1), will make the program print C?

Select the two correct answers.

```
(a) public char getGrade() { return grade; }

(b) public int getGrade() { return grade; }

(c) abstract public int getGrade();

(d) abstract public char getGrade();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GOOD('C')
{ public char getGrade() { return grade; } },
BETTER('B') { public char getGrade() { return grade; } },
BEST('A')
{ public char getGrade() { return grade; } };
private char grade;
```

**Problem** with the sample code is that `grade` is declared as `private`. so `grade` is not accessible from its subclasses. 
Either `grade` should be accessible from its subclasses or subclasses of `Scale2` should access `grade` through `super.getGrade()` method.

```
// (1) INSERT CODE HERE
public char getGrade() { return grade; } // inserted!
```

You have inserted the possibly correct code in your post, and **yes**, the book is wrong.